# Система конфигурации не прошла инициализацию

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity

Доброго времени суток!

Пишу программу с использованием EF6 + MySQL. После запуска, при выполнении программы, выдает такой эксепшион:

```
Система конфигурации не прошла инициализацию ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:  Неизвестный раздел конфигурации entityFramework.
```

Собственно, мой App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DeveloperConnection" 
             providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
             connectionString="server=localhost;UserId=root;Password=;database=mobiledb;CharSet=utf8;Persist Security Info=True" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices,            MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=7.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
      </provider></providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Не могу понять, ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: Вы в configSections не указали секцию entityFramework

Comment: Да, уже исправил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам задал - сам ответил. Необходимо, как уже сказал tym32167, добавить в configSections секцию entityFramework:

```
<configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
```